# C - inline assembly, storing a number goes wrong

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm pretty new to assembly. Actually, I never touched it before, and I kinda need to use it within the school project (I don't really need it, but I find it somehow necessary). I can't use variables, so What I need to do is an assembly code that will move a number to eax (or other register), and with another function it will compare input with the value in register - if that's possible. I'm doing this in C using asm function, but the assembly part is the one that needs fixing.. AT&T syntax, linux, compiling with gcc -std=gnu99, some values I tried:

Flag : Curr : Result

1 : 0 : equal,

0 : 0 : equal,

-1 : 0 : equal,

1 : 1 : smaller

0 : 1 : smaller

-1 : 1 : smaller

1 : -1 : larger

0 : -1 : larger

1 : -1 : larger

so the flag is being overwritten to 0 all the time, how do I prevent that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void setFlag(), compare(), smaller(), larger(), equal();
int getFlag(), getCurr();

int main()
{
    setFlag();
    compare();
    return 0;
}

void setFlag()
{
    asm("movl %0, %%ebx;"
        :: "r" (getFlag())
        : "%ebx");
}

void compare()
{
    asm("cmpl %0, %%ebx;"
        "je 2f;"
        "jg 1f;"

        "call smaller;"
        "jmp 3f;"

        "1:"
        "call larger;"
        "jmp 3f;"

        "2:"
        "call equal;"

        "3:"
        :: "r" (getCurr()));    
}

void smaller() { printf("smaller\n"); }

void larger() { printf("larger\n"); }

void equal() { printf("equal\n"); }

int getFlag() { return 5; }

int getCurr() { return 3; }
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain what this is attempting to do?  For example, `inEax` is doing something with the `eax` register, but it isn't clear what, or why.

Comment: inEax is just supposed to get the value from eax and print it to console, that's why it is moving value from eax to a

Comment: Use proper prototype declarators! And there is no guarantee the compiler will not reorder the statements. And use the debugger! "My code isn't working is no **specific** problem description.

Comment: the hell is proper prototype declarator? and why would compiler reorder statements? yes, the SPECIFIC problem description is above the code, how about you read it?

Comment: It may reorder statements as an optimization. As for inline assembler and gcc I suggest you read this [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). Half way through the document it discusses potential reordering of separate _asm_ blocks, deletion of _asm_ blocks altogether, along with suggested changes to avoid these problems.

Comment: Look at assembly produced by *gcc*, either by using a debugger in disassembler more, or using `-S` switch to get assembly output from *gcc*.

Comment: while that is great I have no idea how to use that output from gcc

Answer (score 0):

Here's the disassembly of your compare function:

```
  00000000004005e0 <compare>:
  4005e0:   b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax
  4005e5:   39 c0                   cmp    %eax,%eax
  4005e7:   74 10                   je     4005f9 <eq>
  4005e9:   7f 07                   jg     4005f2 <lrg>
  4005eb:   e8 10 00 00 00          callq  400600 <smaller>
  4005f0:   eb 0c                   jmp    4005fe <out>
```

Notice anything?

You're mixing your metaphors.  When using %0, etc, you can't use %%eax directly.  The compiler may assign %0 to %eax because you didn't tell it that you wanted to use it.

What you need is a register specific constraint.  The constraint for %eax is "a".  Then apply that.  For example, if you had two registers, and one had to be %eax, do `=a (p), =r (q)`.  Now the p variable [using %0] maps to %eax and the q variable [using %1] maps to any available register.

**HOWEVER** After calling inEax, which stuffs %eax, it has no chance of not being overwritten immediately.  In fact, you can't expect *any* register to have *any* specific state/value after a function returns.

You *can* do this if you put all your assembly code in a manually crafted .s file.  You can have whatever calling conventions you want (e.g. return value in %ecx)

Comment: well, I changed the setFlag to move value into ebx instead of eax, the code looks as this; http://pastebin.com/LpcbZgdH but I'm getting "smaller" now all the time, no matter what number I put as flags, I even tried moving the flag value to the eax and compare eax with ebx (all in compare function) but got the same result

Comment: edit: updated main post with more information and what's going on